# Binary Translation not working in VMware Workstation 12

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, vt-x

Since upgrading my whole PC I am unable to run VMs in Binary Translation mode.

VT-x / Intel Virtualisation Technology is enabled in the BIOS however I require Binary Translation for use in Windows 95. Using VT-x works fine for the rest of my guests. The virtualization mode in the VM is set to binary translation, however I get the error below.

Is there another setting I need to set? Windows, VMWare, BIOS or VMX?

---

- VMWare Version:  12.5.9 build-7535481
- Windows Version: Windows 10, 64-bit  (Build 15063) 10.0.15063
- CPU: Intel i9 7900X (Skylake-X)
- Motherboard: Asus TUF X299 Mark 2

---

Error when VM mode set to Binary Translation:

```
VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (vcpu-0)

vcpu-0:VERIFY vmcore/vmm/main/cpuid.c:386 bugNr=1036521
```

I have read that people with AMD Ryzen CPUs have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that newer CPUs (Ryzen and Skylake-X) no longer support Binary Translation.

I installed VMWare worksation 14 and this option is no longer there. I also tried to rollback 12, but the same issue is still there.

Regardless, Workstation 14 solves the problem.

Comment: Binary translation is [no](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/596743#2801178) [longer](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/586684#2763973) supported in Workstation 14. While *maybe-ish* 12 just had some [incompatibility](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/5x7sk6/vmware_workstation_125_vms_on_ryzen/dlstn8w/) with those quite newer CPUs (indeed, Skylake and Ryzen are mentioned almost in the opening of the 14's release notes).

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there another setting I need to set?

Yes, in the VM settings:

> To configure processor settings for a selected virtual machine, select
>   VM > Settings, click the Hardware tab, and select Processors.
>
> Select the preferred execution mode for the virtualization engine. You
>   usually do not need to change virtualization engine settings.
>
> **Automatic**
>
> Workstation Pro chooses the execution mode based on the guest
>   operating system and the host CPU.
>
> **Binary translation**
>
> Workstation Pro uses a mix of directly executing guest code and binary
>   translation to run the guest operating system. Guest memory mapping is
>   performed by using shadow page tables.
>
> **Intel VT-x or AMD-V**
>
> Workstation Pro uses hardware extensions to run and isolate guest
>   code. Guest memory mapping is performed by using shadow page tables.
>
> **Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI**
>
> Workstation Pro uses hardware extensions to run and isolate guest
>   code. Guest memory mapping is performed by using hardware paging.

Source [Configuring Virtual Machine Processor Settings](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/12.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-3140DF1F-A105-4EED-B9E8-D99B3D3F0447.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have Binary translation set in the VM options, but it shows the error above. I will update the question. Apologies for not being totally clear.